# Should I worry about memory leaks due to not removing event handlers?

Tags: vuejs2, memory-leaks, dom-events, vuetify.js

I recently had to add event handler to `vuetify` dialog's overlay and it works.

Opening / closing dialog is controlled by a boolean variable `dialog`:

```html
<v-dialog v-model="dialog">
  <MyComponent v-if="dialog" />
</v-dialog>
```

And some codes to add / remove handler:

```js
    openDialog() {
      this.dialog = true
      setTimeout(() => {
        const overlay = document.querySelector('.v-overlay--active .v-overlay__scrim')
        if (overlay) {
          overlay.addEventListener('my-event', this.myEventHandler)
        }
      }, 100)
    },
    closeDialog() {
      const overlay = document.querySelector('.v-overlay--active .v-overlay__scrim')
      if (overlay) {
        overlay.removeEventListener('my-event', this.myEventHandler)
      }
      this.dialog = false
    },
```

My concern is that, as `closeDialog` is not always called (e.g. when clicking outside of the dialog), do I need to worry about memory leaks in this case?

The dialog overlay seems like getting inserted / deleted by `vuetify` library and I'm not sure if these changes will make trouble or not.

Answer (score 0):

My question was quite `vuetify` specific. I didn't know the existence of event `click:outside` available for `v-dialog`. Also I had to make the dialog persistent and handle keyup event for `esc` to dismiss the dialog:

```html
// @keyup.esc="handleEsc" somewhere close to top
<v-dialog v-model="dialog" persistent @click:outside="closeDialog">
  <MyComponent v-if="dialog" />
</v-dialog>
```

So now I'm explicitly handling all events to dismiss the dialog and confident that no need to worrying about memory leaks.